# How can I implement Post API call using Dart http library, flutter

Tags: api, http, post, dart, flutter

I was trying to perform a `POST` request using **http** Dart library in flutter. But I was unable to find a way to specify the Request body. Can someone help with an example? Thank you so much

Answer (score 15):

First specify the `http` package in your `pubspec.yaml` like

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.11.3+16
```

then just import and use it.
The minimal example would look like:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

static Future<Map> getData() async {
  http.Response res = await http.get(url); // get api call
  Map data = JSON.decode(res.body);
  return data;
}

static Future<Map> postData(Map data) async {
  http.Response res = await http.post(url, body: data); // post api call
  Map data = JSON.decode(res.body);
  return data;
}
```

To create `http.Client` and use it for api calls

```
 //To use Client and Send methods

 http.Client client = new http.Client(); // create a client to make api calls

 Future<Map> getData() async {
  http.Request request = new http.Request("GET", url);  // create get request
  http.StreamedResponse response = await client.send(request); // sends request and waits for response stream
  String responseData = await response.stream.transform(UTF8.decoder).join(); // decodes on response data using UTF8.decoder
  Map data = JSON.decode(responseData); // Parse data from JSON string
  return data;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What I want to know is how to implement this using Request object and Client.send method.

Comment: I've edited the answer to implement the same, Not, the example works for my use case. Depending on your use case, apply transformers and other data mutation operations. Hope it helps.

Comment: How handle http cookie, reading http cookie after response and sending cookie in request?

Comment: @HemanthRaj 1st part and 2nd part I understand is get and post. But the last part is HttpClient getData what is it used for? How it differs from 1st method?

Comment: Its just another way to make getRequest, similar to that you can make post too. I just wanted to show another way to make requests. However you can just use the finest one.

Comment: How can I add header in GET request Api

Comment: The `http.Request` takes a `headers` property.